# 18.04 recently lost tap-to-click at login (gdm)

Tags: touchpad, 18.04, gdm

I recently lost tap-to-click ability at the login screen (gdm). I originally enabled it in 17.10 and it survived into 18.04 until a few days ago. So I'm not sure what happened.

I followed instructions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Enabling_tap-to-click) by doing:

```
sudo -u gdm gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
```

But I'm getting this error message:

> (process:26095): dconf-CRITICAL **: 17:43:24.120: unable to create
>   directory '/home/user/.cache/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will
>   not work properly.
>
> (process:26095): dconf-WARNING **: 17:43:24.120: failed to commit
>   changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused

And when I run to try and fix:

```
sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
```

I get this:

> (process:26477): dconf-WARNING **: 17:52:56.774: failed to commit
>   changes to dconf:
>   GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code2:
>   Cannot open dconf database: Failed to open file
>   “/home/user/.config/dconf/user”: Permission denied

I decided to try deleting ~/.cache/dconf and tried again to no avail.

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Edited to add more info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this: [Enable ‘Tap to click’ in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/enable-tap-to-click-ubuntu-17-10-login-screen/). It worked for me.

> 1. Open terminal via Ctrl+Alt+T, then run command to get root privileges:
>
>    ```
>    sudo -i
>    ```
>
>    Type in your password (no visual feedback while typing) when it prompts and press Enter.
> 2. (Not required in default Wayland session) Allow user gdm to create a connection to the X server:
>
>    ```
>    xhost +SI:localuser:gdm
>    ```
> 3. Switch to user gdm in the terminal:
>
>    ```
>    su gdm -s /bin/bash
>    ```
> 4. Finally enable 'Tap to click' via gdm user:
>
>    ```
>    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
>    ```
>
>    [image]
> 5. Restart your computer and done.
>
>    ```
>    sudo reboot
>    ```
>
> **How to Restore:**
>
> To restore the setting, open terminal and redo the previous steps
>   except run the following command instead of the command in Step 4:
>
> ```
>     gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click false
> ```

Comment: Worked also in 23.10 with Gnome 45

Comment: In your answer you suggested a link, I had to check that too since this answer did not help in Ubuntu 22.04. In the link, the author suggests `sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true` for 22.04. I don't get the `dbus-launch` part, how do I fit this with your solution? Could you update your post to include a solution for 22.04 too?