# Touchpad click is not working in Ubuntu login screen

Tags: login, touchpad, tap-to-click

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on dual boot. When I turn on my computer, I see the login screen. When I tap there, it doesn't work.I use my keyboard to log in. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: "When I click here": you mean with the touchpad? Hardware click or tap? Edit your answer and provide more detail.

Comment: I mean when I tap

Comment: Use hardware click. I have this issue too. I think it is possible to fix, but I am a bit lazy to do it. It is not important.

Comment: @Pilot6 There is a fix. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04. I upgraded to 20.04 and the problem did not return after the upgrade. It may work for a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.

## Try the following:

1. Open terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then run command to get root privilege:

   sudo -i

Type in your password (no visual feedback while typing) when it prompts and hit <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd>.
2. Allow the user *gdm* to create a connection to the X server:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:gdm
```

3. Switch to user gdm in the terminal:

   su gdm -s /bin/bash
4. Finally enable ‘Tap to click’ via gdm user:

   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true

Finally exit root and close the terminal and reboot and check if tap to click works at the login screen.

Source:

[18.04 recently lost tap-to-click at login (gdm)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032158/18-04-recently-lost-tap-to-click-at-login-gdm)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot..It worked